# C modulo operator behaving unusually with randomly generated integer in my code

Tags: c, random

In the following code of mine, the modulo operator is used on two randomly generated numbers but the output is often incorrect. Why would that happen?

Here's an example of unexpected output:

[image]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay(int number_of_seconds)
{
    // Converting time into milli_seconds
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;

    // Storing start time
    clock_t start_time = clock();

    // looping till required time is not achieved
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds)
        ;
}

void ran_dom(){             //this function generates a random number and prints its remainder
    srand(time(0));
    int x = (int) rand();
    int y = (int) rand();
    printf("x: %d\n", x);
    printf("y: %d\n", y);
    int mod_x = (x % 40);   //modulo operator with value: 40
    int mod_y = (y % 20);   //modulo operator with value: 20
    printf("x mod 40: %d\n", mod_x);
    printf("y mod 20: %d\n", mod_y);
}

void ResetScreenPosition(){     //resets screen position (in windows OS)
    COORD Position;
    HANDLE hOut;
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    Position.X = 0;
    Position.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, Position);

}

void main(){
    while(1){
        ResetScreenPosition();
        ran_dom();
        delay(2);
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Call `srand` *just once* in your code.

Comment: As for your problem.. I would suspect the display. Get rid of this `ResetScreenPosition` call

Comment: That doesn't explain why modulo would produce wrong result, as it does for `x` here. However, it might just be that the `3` there is left over from the last time.

Comment: @underscore_d probably the left-overs of previous prints

Comment: Right. In which case, if confirmed, I would VTC as trivial, because if you're going to print over something, you should pad it enough that it overwrites all previous output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
it cannot be reproduced: https://godbolt.org/z/ih8QMV

Comment: `6327 % 40` is `7`. If the screen has 23 in the position of the 7 from a previous print, printing `"x mod 40: 7"` will appear to have printed `"x mod 40: 73"`. Try `printf("[x mod 40: %d]\n", mod_x);`

Comment: I don't think the question is necessarily off-topic due to reproducibility. The strange runtime behavior is the issue here, and I think it is correctly surmised to be related to how the screen is (or isn't) being cleared.

Comment: I think @pmg is right here. OP is not cleaning the ccreen

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just tried putting the srand in the main method outside the while loop. Still got a wrong output. How do I prevent previous left-overs?

Answer (score 4):

`6327 % 40` is `7`. If the screen has 23 in the position of the 7 from a previous print, printing `"x mod 40: 7"` will appear to have printed `"x mod 40: 73"`.

Try something along the lines of one of these alternatives:

```
printf("x mod 40: %02d \n", mod_x);
printf("[x mod 40: %d]\n", mod_x);
```

Comment: Although I agree with the answer, I don't necessarily agree with the alternatives. It seems as if printing blank spaces and performing a carriage return would resolve the issue. The final alternative probably suffices though.

Comment: @pmg Thanks for your suggestion. The issue is, this code is only a small part of a larger program. I would have to pass the output of the modulo operation to another function, where it will be processed further. Do you think the problem is with leftovers in the buffer and printing, and not with the result of the modulo operator itself?

Comment: @MusaKhan You can easily answer that question for yourself by trying the suggested solution...

Comment: Yes, @MusaKhan. I'm 100% sure the problem **is not** with the modulus calculation.

Comment: @pmg I did try your suggestions and they work. But like I said, I have a larger problem to fix in my head than just this code. I just tried placing a 'system("cls");' inside the while loop in main to clear output screen everytime and that works too. But the output screen refreshes and it shows in my larger program, which is undesirable.

Comment: Just specify sufficient field widths and padding for all your numbers and you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no standard way of clearing the screen in c.
The error in your output came from overwriting the screen without clearing it.

Also there is a sleep(int seconds) function in unistd.h. Using it is probably a better idea than looping.

Calling srand() once is enough. You don't need to set your random seed each call.

This would probably be my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

void clear_screen() {
#ifdef WINDOWS
    system("cls");
#else
    /* Assume POSIX */
    system ("clear");
#endif
}

void print_random() {
    int x, y, mod_x, mod_y;

    x = rand();
    y = rand();
    printf("x: %d\n", x);
    printf("y: %d\n", y);

    mod_x = (x % 40);
    mod_y = (y % 20);
    printf("x mod 40: %d\n", mod_x);
    printf("y mod 20: %d\n", mod_y);
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1) {
        clear_screen();
        print_random();
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since I don't have a Windows machine on hand right now I could only test this code on my Ubuntu. Should work though.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that placing this piece of code after calling delay() from the main function works too:

```
system("cls"); // refreshes screen? works!
```